# MP4Box: Select track by type and language?

Tags: macos, mp4box

For a directory of MP4 files, I want to bulk-change their subtitle tracks that are currently tagged as English `en` to English (United States) `en-US`.

**Is there a way to select subtitle tracks by current language tag**, rather than selecting each subtitle track by its ID number?

I've tried [RTFM](https://www.mankier.com/1/mp4box) to see if I can figure this out myself, but no joy.